# get result of ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm doing the following:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (customarray | orderBy:item[0].nbtickets:true |  limitTo:20 track by $index))" >
    <li ui-sref="app.usersingle({id:item[0].id,iterate:1})" class="row organization"> 
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">{{$index+1}}</div> 
        <div class="name col-md-4 text-center">{{item[0].username}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 total text-center">{{item[0].nbtickets}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 maintenance text-center">{{item[0].tickmaintenance}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 assistance text-center">{{item[0].tickassistance}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And when I want to retrieve data like this in my controller:

```
console.log($scope.filteredItems)
```

I get parse error with bracket

Comment: Can you add any fiddle/plnkr?

Comment: what if you remove `track by $index`? you can still put after `))` if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your syntax is right. According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), to have your ordered and limited list available as a separate variable, you would have to change it to something like:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in customArray | orderBy: item[0].nbtickets: true |  limitTo: 20 as filteredItems track by $index" >
```

I have created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz44g3j7/) which shows it in use.

A further note, from your comments below - in order for the `filteredList` to be logged to the console, it needs to have a slight timeout delay before sending to console - I guess the filtered version is created asynchronously, so it does not exist before the filters have run.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($scope.filteredItems);
}, 100);
```

Comment: @YOU @Starscream1984 Your syntax is right, i don't get any error in my console but when in my controller i'm doing `console.log($scope.filteredItems)`, it give me `undefined` in my console

Comment: Hmm, what do you get if you do `console.log($scope.customArray)`?

Comment: I get my customarray which is normal but i didn't get values orderBy nb-tickets and limited by 20

Comment: Does $watch can have some any utility here ?

Comment: @moskitos - I have expanded my answer and added a link to a fiddle, demonstrating it. I spotted a typo in my initial answer, but the main reason you couldn't log filtered items was an async timing issue :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and your great explannation!